# CodeIgniter methods won't load on Openshift

Tags: php, codeigniter, openshift

I've been going round and round on the CodeIgniter forum on this issue. So I'll try it here. I can't get any of my methods to load in CodeIgniter. I'm running my application on OpenShift.

If I load the model this way "$this->load->model('nav_m_model')", I get a blank screen. If I load the model this way "$this->load->model('nav_m')", I get the CI error message:

> An Error Was Encountered 
>   Unable to locate the model you have specified: nav_m

Here's my code.

controllers/welcome.php

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->model('nav_m');
}

public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    $this->load->view('footer');
}
private function create_menu() {
    $data['query'] = $this->nav_m->get_active_albums();
    print_r($data);
}
}

/* End of file welcome.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/welcome.php */`
```

models/nav_m_model.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Nav_m_model extends CI_Model {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
}

public function get_active_albums() {
    $query = $this->db->get_where('albums', array('is_active' = 1));

    return $query->result();
}
}
```

Finally, no matter which way I do it, I get the follow error in the logs:

> [09/Dec/2014:10:04:06 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 1183 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/600.1.25 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Safari/600.1.25"

I'm not sure if there's a setting somewhere that I'm missing or what. But this has me extremely frustrated.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, this:

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('albums', array('is_active' = 1));
```

should be:

```
// => instead of = in array declaration
$query = $this->db->get_where('albums', array('is_active' => 1));
```

Comment: Just fixed that, but that didn't fix my main problem.

Comment: 1) Make sure you use `$this->load->model('nav_m_model')`. 2) Did/does it work on localhost? 3) Does the view load properly when you omit any references to that particular model? 4) Have you set error reporting to E_ALL?

Comment: 1) With the code above, if I do that, I just get a white screen. I've changed the filename to /models/Nam_m.php. I also call it now with $this->load->model('Nav_m').

2) Yes it works local.

3) Yes, when the model isn't referenced the view works properly.

4) Yes.